# Quickest method to query an enormous array from an Android app?

Tags: android, arrays, server

I have a .tsv/.csv file of certain attributes and info. The file looks like this:

```
attribute 1, info 1  
attribute 2, info 2  
attribute 3, info 3  
attribute 4, info 4  
...
```

There are over 10,000 lines, and since each line has 2 strings (with spaces, numbers, and letters, separated by a comma), the size of this file is far too large to download onto the phone for every user that uses the app. I would like a simple, quick-to-implement solution that allows me to query this array from the app, for instance by the app asking "attribute 2", it will return "info 2".

I have looked into these methods:
 - **AWS**: This requires several languages, with the ability to receive queries from an android app, and return some value. As far as I know, this needs ajax/JS/node and other APIs, but I am only familiar with JS, and take too long to setup.
 - **Website**: This would entail uploading the array to a password-protected website, as raw HTML. However, to read data off this website, I would have to download all the data, which defeats the purpose. Perhaps some sort of web scraper would suffice to just query this website?
 - **SQL**: This would require an SQL database to be downloaded to the user's device, which would likely take up several MB of space. Would this total be added to the size of the app when displayed in the app store?

Comment: Do you need to store the whole file or just query the data in it?

Comment: @cricket_007 I only need to periodically query, so the file should be on the cloud preferably; on the device it will take up a lot of space.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [parse.com](http://parse.com).  You can easily upload a CSV file and then query it from Android.  The only caveat is if you're expecting really heavy transaction load you could run into trouble.

Comment: How do you upload the CSV file and query it? I have finished the tutorial, but cannot find a way to do this. Is there another stack overflow question or tutorial you can point me to (or your own explanation)?

Comment: Create an account, create an application (if you haven't already), go to the data browser (Core), and click Create a Class.  http://blog.parse.com/announcements/import-your-csv-data-to-parse/

Comment: It asks, when creating class, for "custom, user, installation, role, or product." Should I choose custom? The tutorial you linked doesn't specify.

Comment: Oh! The beta data browser does not yet have an import button, that was the problem.

Comment: Ah I see, yeah it has some bugs.  And if you didn't figure it out already choose Custom.